# Remove all elements but keep selected with structure using Cheerio/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

I want to specify which elements I want to keep, but with it's structure.
Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta xx>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="some1">
            <div class="some1-1"></div>
            <div class="some1-2"></div>
            <div class="some1-3"></div>
            <div class="some1-4"></div>
            <div class="some1-5"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="some2">
            <div class="some2-2">
                <div class="some2-2-1"></div>
                <div class="some2-2-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="some2-3"></div>
            <div class="some2-4"></div>
            <div class="some2-5"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I need to **keep** only for example:
.some2-2-1, .some-2-3, .some-1-3, by removing all other elements, and with preserving it's parents so it'll be:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta xx>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="some1">
            <div class="some1-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="some2">
            <div class="some2-2">
                <div class="some2-2-1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="some2-3"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't specify what elements I want to delete (it's dynamic) but only which one I want to keep, how to accomplish it?

`$('*:not('.some2-2-1, .some-2-3, .some-1-3')').remove()`
won't work in that case ;)

Comment: Your sample HTML is a bit inconsistent/confusing. Why does the descendants of `some1` begin with `some1-2` and not `some1-1`? Why is there no `some2-1`? You also say you want to keep `some2-3-1` but that's nowhere to be found in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there'll be several ways of doing this, but here's one way (see comments):

```js
$(function() {
    var elementsToKeep = [
        ".some2-2-1",
        ".some2-3",
        ".some1-3",
    ];

    // parent elements that are needed will be appended here
    var needed = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < elementsToKeep.length; i++) {
        // get the hierarchy, e.g. ".some2-2-1" -> "2-2-1"
        var hierarchyPos = elementsToKeep[i].replace(".some", "");

        // if we're keeping 2-2-1, we also need 2-2, and 2
        //
        // recursively remove the last two characters to get
        // the parent level until there's nothing left
        while (hierarchyPos !== "") {
            if (!needed.includes(hierarchyPos)) {
                needed.push(hierarchyPos);
            }

            hierarchyPos = hierarchyPos.slice(0, -2);
        }
    }

    // "needed" will now contain 2-2-1, 2-2, 2, etc.
    console.log("all required elements:", needed.join(", "));

    // iterate through each of the original selectors
    $(elementsToKeep.join(",")).each(function() {

        // check each of this element's siblings and remove
        // any whose class isn't included in the "needed" array
        var siblings = $(this).siblings();

        siblings.each(function(i, el) {
            var pos = el.className.replace("some", "");

            // if "pos" is 2-2-2 (for example), it won't appear in "needed",
            // so it's safe to remove
            if (!needed.includes(pos)) {
                $(el).remove();
            }
        })
    })

    // finished
    console.log("final output:");
    console.log($("#test").html());
})
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <div class="some1">
        <div class="some1-1"></div>
        <div class="some1-2"></div>
        <div class="some1-3"></div>
        <div class="some1-4"></div>
        <div class="some1-5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="some2">
        <div class="some2-2">
            <div class="some2-2-1"></div>
            <div class="some2-2-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="some2-3"></div>
        <div class="some2-4"></div>
        <div class="some2-5"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```